# Find the determinant of matrix $n \times n$.

Tags: matrices, determinant

Given the matrix:
$$A_{n}=\begin{bmatrix}
e^x&e^{2x}& \cdots &e^{nx}\\
e^x&2e^{2x}& \cdots &ne^{nx}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
e^x&2^{n-1}e^{2x}& \cdots &n^{n-1}e^{nx}\end{bmatrix}$$
I need to prove that $\det(A_n) \neq 0$.

---

I've found det for $A_3$ and $A_4$. But how to find det for common case $A_n$? (or at least show that it is not zero)[image]

Comment: maybe with induction and use of Laplace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\det(A_n)&=e^{x+2x+\cdots+nx}\begin{vmatrix}1&1&\ldots&1\\1&2&\ldots&n\\1^2&2^2&\ldots&n^2\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\1^{n-1}&2^{n-1}&\ldots&n^{n-1}\end{vmatrix}\\&=e^{\frac{n(n+1)}2x}\prod_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}(i-j)\\&\neq0.\end{align}The second equality comes from the fact that the matrix from the first line is a Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: I have another question to this task. If e^x, e^2x, ... , e^nx - fundamental system of solutions of Linear differential equation how to find form of equation?

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is
$$e^{x+2x+\cdots+nx}\left|\matrix{1&1&\cdots&1\\1&2&\cdots&n\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\1&2^{n-1}&\cdots&n^{n-1}}\right|.$$
This is a [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and is nonzero.

Comment: I have another question to this task. If e^x, e^2x, ... , e^nx - fundamental system of solutions of Linear differential equation how to find form of equation?

Comment: @НиколайЖурба Write $D$ for $d/dx$. Then $f(D)y=0$ has solutions $e^{a_1x},\ldots,e^{a_nx}$ where $f(t)=(t-a_1)\cdots(t-a_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your determinant is the Wronskian (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) of the following set 
$$\{e^{x},e^{2x},\ldots,e^{nx}\}.$$